# How to write a property in the link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue.js and do a task in which I need to write a property to a link, but I don’t know how to do it? How do I write "counter" from "data" to a link so that it works.

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      counter: 1,
    }
  },
  created(){
    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts? 
      _start=${counter}+0&_limit=10').then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wh8sbdm1/ - the key is surrounding the string with back-tics vs quotes ` vs " or ' --- also, you need to use `this.counter` vs `counter` ..

Comment: you can access the variable with `this` keyword. so in your case, it would be ${this.counter} and moreover, it should be enclosed with the back tick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Template literals** and they "are string literals allowing embedded expressions" so as suggested by Matt, instead of using a " or ' use (backtick or `) see more here: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Moreover by using `this` you can access the variable since `counter` belongs to data object which is a global object and "**global object** is an object that always exists in the global scope" and using "**this**" keyword you can access a global object at global level. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) and [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-context-this-keyword-9a78a19d5786) so:

```
created(){
  axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+0&_limit=10`).then(response => {
    this.posts = response.data
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios allows you to add URL query parameters as an object:

```
axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    params: {
      _start: this.counter, //or `${this.counter}+0` if you need that +0 as a string at the end
      _limit: 10

    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    this.posts = response.data
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

This will yield the same result but it looks a bit more elegant and easier to maintain once you have a lot of parameters in your URLs

I keep [this axios cheat sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) close by for when I'm working with it.